# Align nested DIV to Bottom of Parent DIV - Responsive - Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking for a way to align a nested `div` to the bottom of the parent `div`.

I do not want to use position: absolut:

```
#child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

This breaks my responsive design as content will start to overlap if the screen is resized. The paren container looks like this:

CSS

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<header id="parent" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="overlapped-content" class="row">
            ... some regular content ...
        </div>
        <div id="child" class="row">
            <div id="lower-intro" class="container-fluid">
                ... to lower content
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

If the screen is resized the `overlapped-content` will be overlaped by the `child` content.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: if the parent div are relative to html,body{height:100%} , maybe you can divide the divs with first div to use 90% height and second div to use 10%... else I dont know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-height on overlapped-content or You can set it's height.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. The overlapped content is a responsive image. So I am not sure if setting a height will be a good idea?

Comment: if i think good responsive image = 100% width image. than you can set its parent divs height, it wont do anyithing with your responsive image.